# How do I add an array of pivot table data to a user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a pivot table of user_activities. I already have the relationship defined in the model, for example:

```
$activities = User::find($id)->activities;
```

This returns an array of objects. I want to send the user object with the activities array.

I've tried dynamically assigning this activities array to the user object but I only get an empty object as a result (`$user->activities = {}`) instead of the array full of activity objects. How do I add this array of activity objects to the user object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try following approach (your approach should work, related models will be loaded later on call (dynamically) but this is better, known as [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)):

```
$user = User::with('activities')->find($id);
```

Make sure you have declared the relationship properly and have related models as well.

Comment: That's exactly it.  Will accept answer in 9 minutes.